# How to create regular expresion from Grafana variables. Influx 2.0DB

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I have this query that pulls branch information from GIT. I would like to be able to filter the data by the variable "epic". In Grafana, I have the epic data pulled from the database and it can be selected from a dropdown list witch checkbox for each epic (multiselect).

```
from(bucket: "my_bucket")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "my_measure")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "Score")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["epic"] == "${epic_db}")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "mean")
```

But when i select more than one epic on list, i got this:

```
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["epic"] == "{epic-1,epic-2}")
```

Which is not working like the SQL IN statement (WHERE epic IN (epic1, epic2, etc).
The thing that is working for me, is to build the regex like this

```
filter(fn: (r) => r["epic"] =~ /epic1|epic2|epic3/
```

But i have no idea, how to build such a regex, by using this drop-down-check-list with variables in Grafana. I was trying all that stuff like:

```
 "/${epic_db}/"
```

But is not working. Any ideas, how to make it possible using InfluxDB2.0 with Flux?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the variable formatting options documentation [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/advanced-variable-format-options/).

Basically grafana allows you to choose how the variable is formatted in your query. In your case you can do something like this:

```
from(bucket: "my_bucket")
 |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
 |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "my_measure")
 |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "Score")
 |> filter(fn: (r) => r["epic"] =~ /${epic_db:regex}/)
 |> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)
 |> yield(name: "mean")
```

This way you can use the build in regex functionality of the flux query language.